# video.onended + redirect not working in safari (only mac)

Tags: html, macos, video, safari

I've small problem which occurs only in Safari on Mac.
When video on this page http://tmp.vokracko.cz ends, it does not redirect as it should.
(And it work everywhere else, even in Safari on Windows)

Redirect code:

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
video.onended = function(e) {
    window.location = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.length - 10) + 'home.html';
};
```

Do you have any ideas why?
I can't test it and debug properly since I dont have a Mac.

Comment: Just another proof that safari (and mac) are bad.

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#mediaevents) the event is endend, and not onended. But maybe all browers don't implement it.